# Categorizing my foreach loop result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, foreach

My SQL result getResult have many rows which have different values in each column of Header and SubHeader, so I wanted it to be categorized, and now i would like to add a total result per each subHeader counting the getResult rows

```
$header = "";
$subHeader = "";
$getResult = "";

foreach($QueryMySql as row):

if($header != $row->headerColumn)
{
   $header = $row->headerColumn."<br />";
   $get .= $header;
}
if($subHeader != $row->subHeaderColumn)
{ 
   $subHeader = $row->subHeaderColumn."<br />";
   $get .= $subHeader;  
}
   $getResult = $row->getResultColumn."<br />";
   $get .= $getResult;

endforeach;
```

**RESULT**

> ---
>
> USA Location(Header)
>
> ICT Department(SubHeader)
>
> 1 (emp_name)getResult
>
> 2 (emp_name)getResult
>
> 3 (emp_name)getResult
>
> total: 3 <- this is what i wanted to add in my output
>
> Accounting Department(Subheader)
>
> 1 (emp_name)getResult
>
> 2 (emp_name)getResult
>
> 3 (emp_name)getResult
>
> 4 (emp_name)getResult
>
> ### total: 4 <- this is what i wanted to add in my output
>
> Pakistan(Header)
>
> ICT Department(SubHeader)
>
> 1 (emp_name)getResult
>
> 2 (emp_name)getResult
>
> 3 (emp_name)getResult
>
> 4 (emp_name)getResult
>
> total: 4 <- this is what i wanted to add in my output
>
> ---
>
> India(Header)
>
> Engineering Department(SubHeader)
>
> 1 (emp_name)getResult
>
> 2 (emp_name)getResult
>
> 3 (emp_name)getResult
>
> 4 (emp_name)getResult
>
> total: 4 <- this is what i wanted to add in my output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i understood is you want to calculate column, if no knidly update your desired output, if yes then use this code which will count all records and save result in output:

```
$grandTtoal = 0;$tempHeader='';$tempSubHeader='';
foreach($QueryMySql as $OneRow){
    if($tempHeader == '' || $tempHeader != $OneRow->headerColumn)
    {
       echo $tempHeader = $OneRow->headerColumn."<br />";
    }
    if($tempSubHeader =='' || $tempSubHeader != $OneRow->subHeaderColumn)
    { 
       echo $tempSubHeader = $OneRow->subHeaderColumn."<br />"; 
    }
    for($i=0; $i<mysql_num_fields($OneRow);$i++ )
    {
         echo ($i+1).' '.$OneRow[$i]->getResultColumn."<br />";
    }
    echo "Total: ".$i;
    $grandTtoal += $i;        
}
echo "Grand Total: ".$grandTtoal;
```

Second option.

```
$grandTtoal = 0;$tempHeader='';$tempSubHeader='';
    foreach($QueryMySql as $OneRow){
        if($tempHeader == '' || $tempHeader != $OneRow->headerColumn)
        {
           echo $tempHeader = '<h1>'.$OneRow->headerColumn.'</h1>'."<br />";
        }
        if($tempSubHeader =='' || $tempSubHeader != $OneRow->subHeaderColumn)
        { 
           echo $tempSubHeader = '</h4>'.$OneRow->subHeaderColumn.'</h4>'."<br />"; 
        }
        for($i=0; $i<mysql_num_fields($OneRow);$i++ )
        {
             echo ($i+1).' '.$OneRow[$i]->getResultColumn."<br />";
        }
        echo "Total: ".mysql_num_fields($OneRow);
        $grandTtoal += mysql_num_fields($OneRow);        
    }
    echo "Grand Total: ".$grandTtoal;
```

Comment: Hi Imran, where should i put that in my code? what i wanted is to have stucture like the one that is shown above, not just counting the result

Comment: it perfectly worked! thanks Imran! you save my life from devastation

Comment: you welcome, i more thing if you want to distinguish with header sub header row then you can try second sol.

Comment: both are perfectly working! you're an amazing person Imran, but how can i change the mysql_num_fields into codeigniter format? do you have any idea?

Comment: $query->num_fields() is equilant in codeigniter which count number of fields in query result

Comment: in this case you can use count($OneRow, COUNT_RECURSIVE); instead

Comment: Imran there's a little problem when i just put my TOTAL inside my foreach this is what happened Header 1

SubHeader 1

1 getResult
total: 1 |
2 getResult
total: 1 |
3 getResult
total: 1|

Comment: what i wish to happen is to count the employees(getResult) per Department(SubHeader) and total their number at the bottom of the last row of the employee.

Comment: remove .' '.$headerCount and .' '.$tempHeaderCount from echo row

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution.

```
$head =array();$i = $j = $k = 1;
foreach($QueryMySql as $row){
    if($row->headerColumn == 'Header1'){
         if(!in_array('Header1', $head)){
            echo $row->headerColumn."<br/>";
            echo $row->subHeaderColumn."<br/>";
            $head[]   = $row->subHeaderColumn;     
         } 

         echo $i . $row->getResultColumn."<br />";
         $i++;

    }elseif($row->headerColumn == 'Header2') {
        if(!in_array('Header2', $head)){
            echo $row->headerColumn."<br/>";
            echo $row->subHeaderColumn."<br/>";
            $head[]   = $row->subHeaderColumn;     
         } 

         echo $j . $row->getResultColumn."<br />";
         $j++;

    }elseif($row->headerColumn == 'Header3') {
        if(!in_array('Header3', $head)){
            echo $row->headerColumn."<br/>";
            echo $row->subHeaderColumn."<br/>";
            $head[]   = $row->subHeaderColumn;     
         } 

         echo $k . $row->getResultColumn."<br />";
         $k++;
    }        
}
```

Comment: Hi richie, the headers and subheader is just a sample i made, because that is categorized for example the headers are the locations and subheaders are the department name, and the getresults are the employees from each locations and department, it is returned by SQL Query i made. thanks!